# Capybara can't find element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I can't get Capybara to find an element here;

```
<div class="block__body">
  <div class="programme-list">
    <div class="programme-item">
      <div class="programme-item__header">
        <svg class="icon icon--type">
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icons-flexi"></use>
        </svg>
        <h3 class="programme-item__title">Flexi programmes</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="programme-item__body">
        <ul class="list-style-none">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress__status">
              <div class="progress__total">
                <span class="progress__label">
                  Total <strong>£265000</strong>
                </span>
              </div>
              <a class="action action--link action--understate" href="/sponsors/1/programmes/sport-fit-scheme-1">
                <span class="action__label">Sport Fit Scheme</span>
                <!--<svg class="icon icon--arrow">
                  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icons-chevron-right"></use>
                </svg>-->
              </a>
```

This is my code in my rspec file.

```
scenario 'Update programme' do
  programme = create(
    :programme,
    id: 2,
    name: 'Acme Two Programme',
    description: 'The description for the Acme Two Programme',
    account: create(:account)
  )

  sign_in_as(admin)

  click_link 'Programmes'

  within(:css, '.programme-list') do
    within(:css, '.programme-item') do # this does not work...
    end
  end
```

The error I get is;

`Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css ".programme-item"`

Why can't it find the element? Is it because I have several of these elements in theory with the same name? If so, how can I specify just one?

Comment: Don't worry. I hadn't actually saved the programme to the sponsor using `sponsor.programmes << programme` so technically there were no programmes to loop through. Doh!

Comment: ps - if, like me, you didn't already know this - `save_and_open_page` could have essentially saved me 2 hours today